# Hive External Table - Drop Partition

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-partitions, hiveddl, hive-table

Facing a weird issue. `Alter table` command to drop partition works well for > or < or >= or <= signs but not for = check.

Working command:

```
ALTER TABLE XYZ DROP PARTITION(bizdate>'20231230');
```

Command that's not working and throwing an error stating that partition does not exist:

```
ALTER TABLE XYZ DROP PARTITION(bizdate='20231230');
```

When I do `show partitions`, I can see '20231230' partition.

Note: `bizdate` is a `varchar(10)`

Comment: Do you still see partition `bizdate='20231230'` if you execute `MSCK REPAIR`?

Comment: @mazaneicha yes I can see

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of partition in the table:

```
SHOW PARTITIONS <table>;
```

Perhaps it tries dropping the partition. It seems that the data was removed at some point on HDFS but the hive tables metadata still thinks those partitions exist

```
 ALTER TABLE *tableName* drop if exists PARTITION(bizdate="20231230");
```

& Re-pair the broken [table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-DropPartitions)

```
msck repair table *table_name*;
```